# Text in textArea are not tied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following text area and its not aligned 
between the value of the view bag and the text there is a lot space,how should
I put them tied?

This is the code

```
<div>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40">
        Date @ViewBag.Date
        Subject @ViewBag.Subject
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove rows and cols. It ll take the size of big row. In this case subject line size will be taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to remove the leading and trailing whitespace in the textarea? Make sure there is no whitespace where you don't want them. For example...

```
<div>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40">Date @ViewBag.Date
Subject @ViewBag.Subject</textarea>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3B6Nm/)

Comment: Thanks Anthony,how I put the subject in different line

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. The subject is on a different line. You can put newlines anywhere you'd like. Have a look... http://jsfiddle.net/3B6Nm/

Comment: I remove the spaces but when you do Ctrl+D (like aligned page) this mass up ,there is no way to do it by code like style or somthing ? can I put the text like subject in bold?